# How can I check exchange, queue and topics in QPID like Rabbitmq does?

Tags: amqp, qpid

We are now using QPID as the AMQP solution instead of Rabbitmq, but I cannot find a easy way to to check queues and topics like Rabbitmq does.

Is there any tool in QPID could do this? I see some qpid-stat, qpid-tool, qpidd but that doesn't help. Any sample or doc available? Can't find much in qpid.apache.org.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qpid-tool should show you all the information you are looking for.
Maybe you find this helpful: https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_MRG/1.3/html/Messaging_User_Guide/sect-Messaging_User_Guide-Management_Tools-Using_qpid_tool.html

Comment: thanks, but not as my understand, qpid is provided by Apache, why the detail document is in RedHat page?

Comment: When I run "qpid-config", following error thrown: Failed: AuthenticationFailure: sasl negotiation failed: no mechanism agreed, need to do something in advance? @hveiga

Comment: @JerryCai Disable the authentication with broker by passing this option while running broker. **--auth no**.  
 
If you want authentication(for C++ Broker), go through this link. [Security](http://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-trunk/cpp-broker/book/chap-Messaging_User_Guide-Security.html)